# How to use edimax with parameters "q" and "bq"

Tags: php, solr

I have indexed documents in my solr server and I want to make this query:

```
 $url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/tutorial/select/?defType=edismax&q='.$des1.'%20and%20'.$des2.'%20and%20'.$des3.'+&bq='.$des11.'%20or%20'.$des22.'%20or%20'.$des33.'&start=0&rows=10&wt=php';
```

At first it should match all the variables defined in the "q" parameter, then I need to the documents which match as possible as it can from the "bq" parameter and rank documents depended on how much parameters could the doc match, 
i am applying this query on the admin interface of solr but not having the needed results when writing in php

Comment: If you're getting results you want when you apply them from the admin interface, compare the URLs generated in both cases. They're not the same if you get different results.

Comment: @MatsLindh I am trying to put the same query but it is making error, in php I am passing parameters not string so I am not sure if it's useful  to compare.

Comment: You'll have to show the end URL before making the request at least - that should at least indicate what you're having trouble with, as well as the error generated by Solr.

Comment: You may find it useful moving as many parameters as possible into the default section of the /select handler (in solrconfig.xml). This will minimize number of variables you need to set in PHP.